# inverted triangle using while loop c++

Tags: c++

Cant get to where I need to be. So I need a program using while loops only to get an output of . .

```
123456
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

Given, you enter the number amount of rows and in this case it is 6. My program now displays this

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
```

Any help on inverting this? Program currently appears as . .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int rows;
    int i;
    int j;

    cout << "Enter number of rows: ";
    cin >> rows;

    int k=rows;
    i=1;

    while (i <= rows)
    {  
        j=1;
        while(j <= i)
        {
            cout << j%10;
            j++;
        }
        cout << endl ;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your outer loop can count down from the number of rows, instead of counting up.  That way, the current outer count will also be the number of values to print on the current line.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to have a decreasing number of outputs you have to start your outer loop with the given input and decrease it for every iteration.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int rows;

    cout << "Enter number of rows: ";
    cin >> rows;

    int remainingRows = rows;

    while (remainingRows >= 1) 
    {  
        int outputIndex = 1;
        while(outputIndex <= remainingRows)
        {
            cout << outputIndex%10;
            outputIndex++;
        }
        cout << endl ;
        remainingRows--;
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/mZOt8v)